# inner and outer reduction, same result?

Tags: lisp, racket, operator-precedence

Does inner and outer reduction always create the same value, if not what would cause different ones?

I am talking about Racket, a functional language.

There are I know possibilities where it is more efficient like in Racket but actually causing a different result. I wasn't able to create a case where that happens, but I feel like it should be possible and may be. dangerous not to know.

Example:

```
;inner reduction
    (sqr (* 3 (+ 1 (sqr 2))))
        ->(sqr (* 3 (+ 1 (* 2 2))) ;(sqr)
        ->(sqr (* 3 (+ 1 4)) ;(*)
        ->(sqr (* 3 5)) ;(+)
        ->(sqr 15) ;(*)
        ->(* 15 15) ;(sqr)
        ->225 ;(*)

;outer reduction
    (sqr (* 3 (+ 1 (sqr 2))))
        ->(* (* 3 (+ 1 (sqr 2))) (* 3 (+ 1 (sqr 2))) ;(sqr)
        ->(* (* 3 (+ 1 (* 2 2))) (* 3 (+ 1 (sqr 2))) ;(sqr)
        ->(* (* 3 (+ 1 4)) (* 3 (+ 1 (sqr 2))) ;(*)
        ->(* (* 3 5) (* 3 (+ 1 (sqr 2))) ;(+)
        ->(* 15 (* 3 (+ 1 (sqr 2))) ;(*)
        ->(* 15 (* 3 (+ 1 (* 2 2))) ;(sqr)
        ->(* 15 (* 3 (+ 1 4))) ;(*)
        ->(* 15 (* 3 5)) ;(+)
        ->(* 15 15) ;(*)
        ->225 ;(*)
```

Comment: You can check sicp first chapter. The answer is yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know Racket, but in general you can run into trouble if any of your expressions have side effects, such as modifying variables, doing input/output, etc.

Take the following example:

```
(define x 1)
(sqr (begin (set! x (add1 x)) x))
```

Inner reduction:

```
; x = 1
(sqr (begin (set! x (add1 x)) x))

; x = 2
(sqr (begin x))

; x = 2
(sqr (begin 2))

; x = 2
(sqr 2)

; x = 2
(* 2 2)

; x = 2
4
```

I.e. the result is `4` and the final value of `x` is `2`.

With outer reduction, you get:

```
; x = 1
(* (begin (set! x (add1 x)) x)
   (begin (set! x (add1 x)) x))

; x = 2
(* (begin x)
   (begin (set! x (add1 x)) x))

; x = 2
(* 2
   (begin (set! x (add1 x)) x))

; x = 3
(* 2
   (begin x))

; x = 3
(* 2
   (begin x))

; x = 3
(* 2
   3)

; x = 3
6
```

I.e. the result is `6` and the final value of `x` is `3`.

---

There's another difference. With inner reduction it's possible that you don't get a result at all:

```
(define (my-if c t e)
  (if c t e))

(define (loop)
  (loop))

(my-if #t 42 (loop))
```

With outer reduction:

```
(my-if #t 42 (loop))
; definition of 'my-if'
(if #t 42 (loop))
; built-in 'if'
42
```

With inner reduction:

```
(my-if #t 42 (loop))
; definition of 'loop'
(my-if #t 42 (loop))
; definition of 'loop'
(my-if #t 42 (loop))
; definition of 'loop'
(my-if #t 42 (loop))
; definition of 'loop'
...
```

This never terminates.

Comment: @Xanlantos I got my syntax from https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/set_.html. Isn't that Racket?

Comment: @Xanlantos I added a second example that doesn't use `set!`.

Comment: @Xanlantos I'm pretty sure that your teacher is aware of `set!`, but is trying to teach you how to program without it.